# Term for associations made by a reader between fictional characters and people they know

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there is a term for the mechanism where a reader consciously or unconsciously associates a fictional character with someone they know? *

A conceivable example might be a parent reading about a child character (who is described in general terms) who has an accident or similar and the parent reader may feel grief in excess of a reader who *isn't* a parent. Specifically because they have placed their son or daughter in the scene.

That's just one example, the mechanism I'm interested in isn't particular to parent/child empathy, but more general.

It would happen in narrative drama - TV, film, theatre - also...

It's not just 'association' is it? I'm finding it a hard thing to search for online.

<sub>* The veracity of the association is irrelevant.</sub>

Comment: I think "Identification" is the word you are looking for. But asking about individual words is not really on topic here.

Comment: @mbakeranalecta, Ahhh, yes google is being much more cooperative with that term, thank you!  If you want the rep, go ahead and answer, or you can vote to close as off-topic, your choice  ;)

Comment: *Association* (or a qualification of it like *a reader's personal association*) seems like your best option. It is a term of art in psychology: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(psychology)

Comment: Well it could be allegorical if the writer intends such a correlation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Term for associations made by a reader between fictional characters and people they know"

— We may call such characters 'LIFELIKE'

— Term for such  associations 'IDENTIFICATION ' and the
      situation  'VERISIMILITUDE'

— The characters represent our 'ALTER-EGO'

and when we lose our identify in the identity of the fictional characters and love, like, pity, hate or laugh or cry as the characters do in their make-believe world, the situation may be termed "EXPERIENCE -TAKING" , a new coinage by a group of researchers of Ohio State University.

IDENTIFICATION is the proper term in the present perspective.

Answer (score 0):

[**oneirataxia**](http://wordinfo.info/unit/1476) - (n. The inability to differentiate between fantasy and reality) is a vague word to say the very least.

It is the second result on [Words that mean "association between reality and fantasy" - Writers’ Reverse Dictionary](http://www.writersdictionary.com/search/association+between+reality+and+fantasy?var=sp%3D%2A). The other fourteen results at the beginning make even less sense:

1. twilight zone
2. earth
3. lose
4. ego
5. phantasm
6. loses
7. antibiosis
8. relation
9. metaphysics
10. correlation
11. barth
12. connection
13. relationship
14. communion

Comment: Right after twilight zone :D

Comment: ... "barth" as in John Barth?